# Drawing a png image on a tkinter canvas python

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, tkinter, png, tkinter-canvas

I am trying to create a simple game using `tkinter` in `python 3.5` using the canvas widget. For this game I am need to be able to use a transparent (png) image. Here is my code:

```
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas

root = Tk()
im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="test.png")
canvas = Canvas(root, width=900, height=900)
canvas.pack()
canvasImage = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=im, anchor="nw")
root.mainloop()
```

The problem is that, despite getting no errors i can't load an image with a transparent background but i can load png images with no transparent background.

Answer (score 3):

You should try this:

```
from tkinter import * 
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()
img = PhotoImage(file='path/your_image.png')
canvas.create_image(250, 250, image=img)
root.mainloop()
```

Output [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMYzg.jpg)

Comment: Don't use wildcard imports, instead do `import tkinter as tk`

Comment: @Coal_ In this case a wildcard import is fine; it is not a blanket rule to never use it.

Comment: I agree with you for this particular case, but if you need to have a scalable codebase and have lots of cross-dependencies, wildcard imports are terrible. I mean, it's easier to forget about them now rather than having to prepend `tk` to every object later on.

Comment: When i do this i get '_tkinter.TclError: couldn't recognize data in image file "test.png"'' in my console.